# Submitting Jar file to app store

Tags: java, macos, appstore-approval, code-signing-certificate

Do anyone has bundled a jar file to make an mac os app which is being accepted by app store. 
I have converted an inellij generated standalone jar file to macOS native app. It is working fine on my Mac OS after requiring java installation . But as apple require security singing certificates and it deny any third party installations. 
So i was looking for some resource to sign my app without xCode. I have already generated and downloaded the certificate for mac app from my developers account but i don't know how to sign my app. 
I ll' thankful if someone could help me to find a resource on this matter.

i am using the following apps for bundling and wrapper but it's not working.

for bundling-  https://sourceforge.net/projects/jarappmaker/

for wrapper- http://www.ohanaware.com/appwrapper/appWrapper3update387.dmg

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to sign your app without xCode. Welcome to the world of Apple. Do not pass go, do pay us $100.

Comment: I have seen examples and an app on app store. http://speling.shemnon.com/blog/2014/04/10/getting-your-java-app-in-the-mac-app-store/